# WordPress media-upload how to send data to custom table

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a little plugin in WordPress, and currently using WordPress media-upload.php to upload images.
Thing is, I need to get a copy of the URL of the images that is uploaded, to store in a custom sql-table that I made.

I have no idea how to do this, and can't find anything when searching here or google.
Could be nice if somehow it could return an array of the images uploaded, with the URL or something.

Hope someone can give me a hint. Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably have to use the send_to_editor hook in javascript to get the image paths, and then send them with ajax to a custom PHP scripts that saves them in the DB.

Comment: I don't know how off hand, but since WordPress gives IDs to everything in the database, it may be better to look for the ID of the uploaded image and store that instead of the full URL. This would allow you to easily pull different thumbnail sizes, image meta info, etc also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complex than you might realize, but here's the fundamental building blocks:

1) You have to enqueue the right scripts.  This can be done in your enqueue_scripts action using the [wp_enqueue_media()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media) function.

2) You then need to write some javascript to process the media upload and send it back to your browser.  Here's a *stripped down* version of the code required to make this happen:

```
function mediaUpload(el) {
    // Using the count value as unique identifier
    formfield = $(el).attr('data-count');
    custom_media = true;
    var _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
        if ( custom_media ) {
            console.log(attachment.url);
            // Put your code here to process the image urls...
        } else {
            return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
        };
        clearInterval(button_update);
    }

    wp.media.editor.open(1);

    button_update = setInterval(function() {
         $('div.media-modal a.media-button-insert').html('Use ' + word + '');} 
    ,300);
    return false;
}
```

3) Then you would just need to call when a given button is clicked:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.media_upload_button').click(
        function() {
            mediaUpload($(this));
        }
    );
});
```